# Applescript if statement : greater than and lower than

Tags: applescript, macos

Can I run an script if a variable is between 4 and 6 characters only ?

e.g

```
set serialNumber to ""
set theLength to (get length of (serialNumber as text))
if theLength is equal to 1 then
    set serialNumber to "No Serial"
else if theLength > 4 and < 6 then
    ##do this
else if theLength is greater than 6 then
    ## do nothing
end if
```

This is obviously not working :   `else if theLength > 4 and < 6 then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
else if theLength > 4 and < 6 then
```

To:

```
else if theLength > 4 and theLength < 6 then
```

Or, since you asked "Can I run a script if a variable is between 4 and 6 characters only?", which is equal to `5`, you can also use:

```
else if theLength = 5 then
```

In place of:

```
else if theLength > 4 and theLength < 6 then
```

However, if testing between two numbers that are (*one* or) more then *one*, just use the *variable* twice in the test as shown above.

Comment: For completeness—and given that "*between*" can be inclusive—it's worth including *less than or equal to* (`<=` or `≤`); *greater than or equal to* (`>=` or `≥`); and *not equal to* (`/=` or `≠`).  For example, `if theLength ≥ 4 and theLength ≤ 6 then...` catches `theLength` when its value is 4, 5 or 6; and if we know that `theLength` only evaluates to integers between 1 and 6 inclusive, this conditional is equivalent to the last: `if theLength ≠ 1 and theLength ≠ 2 and theLength ≠ 3`.

Comment: @CJK, IMO It's not totally clear what the OP is actually looking for and why I left it as is, however you made some good points and feel free to edit them into the answer if your wish.

Comment: Although the question is somewhat vague, I think your answer is just fine as it is.  I think my additions serve better as a comment, as it's more of an aside, and not a correction or improvement, per se.

Comment: Thank you that actually perfect, @user3439894 you right I was wrong in my question "< 6 then" (because I'm not sure of the Length yet, I have to check at the office) but anyway that perfect, exactly what I needed, thank you again.